# AWS CloudHSM error on Windows Server: Certificate Request Processor: Provider type not defined. 0x80090017 (-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF)

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2019, signtool, amazon-cloudhsm, certreq

When generating a CSR on Windows Server using the AWS CloudHSM service, I obtain the following error:

```
certreq.exe -new my-request.inf my-request.csr 

Certificate Request Processor: Provider type not defined. 0x80090017 (-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF)
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Credential issue

This error message generally indicates that your credentials to connect to the CloudHSM cluster as a CU user are not correct:

- ensure you are logging in using a CU user (Crypto User) and not a CO (Crypto Officer) user ([more on AWS CloudHSM user management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/manage-hsm-users.html))
- ensure your credentials are correct (typo, issue with copy/paste, extra character).

Additionally, if encountering the following error, this generally means that you haven't set the CloudHSM credentials (see below)

```
n3fips_password env variable not set>
Cfm2Shutdown: Application is not initialized
```

## Tl;dr: set up credentials to use the CloudHSM cluster with Windows SDK tools:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Amazon\CloudHSM\tools\set_cloudhsm_credentials.exe" --username test_cu_user --password xxx

# Securely input the username and password: 
${hsm_creds_user} = Read-Host -AsSecureString "hsm_creds_user"
${hsm_creds_password} = Read-Host -AsSecureString "hsm_creds_password"

# Convert from SecureString to String
$hsm_cu_user = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($hsm_creds_user))
$hsm_cu_pwd = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($hsm_creds_password))

# 
& "C:\Program Files\Amazon\CloudHSM\tools\set_cloudhsm_credentials.exe" --username ${hsm_cu_user} --password ${hsm_cu_pwd}
```

You can now use certreq or signtool.

Source:

- [Use Microsoft SignTool with AWS CloudHSM to Sign Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/signtool.html)
- [Install and Configure the AWS CloudHSM Client (Windows)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/install-and-configure-client-win.html)

Comment: I had a similar error: `Failed to connect socket IP 127.0.0.1 Error:10061
Cfm2Shutdown: Application is not initialized
Certificate Request Processor: Provider type not defined. 0x80090017 (-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF)`. It went away once I started the `AWS CloudHSM Client` Windows Service.